# Using JSoup to get app names from Google Play Store

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to get the name of the application from the Google Play store via JSoup.

For example, if I wanted to use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.hillclimb&hl=en) as a test case, I would only like this to print out:

```
Hill Climb Racing
```

Here's the code I'm using to try and get the name of the app:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.hillclimb&hl=en).get();
Elements link = doc.select("h1.document-title");
System.out.println(link);
```

And here's what's printing out when I run it:

```
<h1 class="document-title" itemprop="name"> 
 <div>
  Hill Climb Racing
 </div> </h1>
```

I'm assuming that I'm really close, because I actually have "Hill Climb Racing" printing out, but there's other undesired information in there as well. I don't know how to best capture only the title.

I thought about doing a substring and capturing what's between the

```
<div>
```

and

```
</div>
```

but that would have to be calculated every time as apps have different length names and thus the substring length would be different every time.

If anybody knows of a better way to capture the desired information (or if I'm on the right track) I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `link` is `Elements` result of `toString` (method invoked by `println`) shows you elements selected from DOM.

If you want to see text which is generated by these elements use `text()` method.

```
System.out.println(link.text()); 
//          add this---^^^^^^^
```